# want to fetch value of closest inner checked radio button using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

want to fetch value of closest inner checked radio button using jquery:

My Code Snippet:

HTML Code Snippet:

```
<div class="rating" data-islogin="<?php echo $this->session->userdata('vhkrt_clt_logged_in')==TRUE ? 1:0;?>" data-userid="<?=$cltId?>" data-prodid="<?=$prod->prod_id?>">
    <input type="radio" id="star5_<?=$prod->prod_id?>" name="rating" value="5" />
    <label class = "full" for="star5_<?=$prod->prod_id?>"></label>
    <input type="radio" id="star4_<?=$prod->prod_id?>" name="rating" value="4" />
    <label class = "full" for="star4_<?=$prod->prod_id?>"></label>
</div>
```

jQuery Code Snippet:

```
$('.rating').click(function(){
    var rating = $(this).closest('input[name = rating]:checked').value;
    alert(rating); //getting "undefined"
})
```

I am trying above code snippet but I am getting **rating value is "undefined" on alert**

Please suggest me proper statement to get checked radio button value.

**I dont want to implement "onchange" event of radio button because of some conditions.**

Comment: You're mixing jQuery and native DOM properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery `closest`  is used to query ancestors , in your case you need child tags.
You could use `children` instead

```js
$('.rating').click(function(){
    var rating = $(this).children(`input[name = 'rating']:checked`).val();
    alert(rating);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="rating" data-islogin="<?php echo $this->session->userdata('vhkrt_clt_logged_in')==TRUE ? 1:0;?>" data-userid="<?=$cltId?>" data-prodid="<?=$prod->prod_id?>">
    <input type="radio" id="star5_<?=$prod->prod_id?>" name="rating" value="5" />
    <label class = "full" for="star5_<?=$prod->prod_id?>"></label>
    <input type="radio" id="star4_<?=$prod->prod_id?>" name="rating" value="4" />
    <label class = "full" for="star4_<?=$prod->prod_id?>"></label>
</div>
```

Comment: two times getting alert.. first showing "undefined" and another showing right value.. why alert getting twice in my case?

Comment: @AnjaliPatil please remove your code, it has only one alert. You can see by using `Run code snippet` button here.

Comment: can you mention the possible reasons.. in my case, why click event getting fired twice.. class rating div is in loop

Comment: you must add full code then, a fiddle or plunker can be useful .

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
$('.rating').click(function(){
    var rating = $(this).find("input[name = 'rating']:checked").val();
})
```

Comment: may be the downvote was before your edit .. where your solution wasnt working .